# Trying to understand why voltage supplies have high in-rush current

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, current-limiting

I have a pair of buck switching converters in a circuit, the [LM2673](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2673.pdf) and the [LM2679](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2679.pdf). However, the LM2679 is being used in a buck-boost configuration as shown in this app note, [AN-1157](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva022e/snva022e.pdf?ts=1598635634497&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM2679), and I'm converting a positive voltage to -10 volts. The LM2673 is being used to convert a DC voltage down to 5 volts. You can see my circuit below:

[image: Schematic]

So far, I've tested it with a bench power supply (in a single-supply configuration with the single supply capable of up to 3 amps), outputting at 12 volts and 15 volts. However, when a load is connected to the output, the power board and load seems to be drawing more current than 3 amps, bringing the bench supply to current-limiting mode (output voltage being around 1-2 volts with current being 3 amps). The work around I've found is to
change out the current-adjust resistors on the regulators (increase them to limit the current to lower values, 1 amp and 3 amps). The problem is that the bench supply can't supply enough current on start-up. When I tested it again in a parallel supply configuration (single voltage, output up to 6 amps), it turns out that with the load I'm working with, the power supply pulls 4 amps of current on startup when the load is attached. When there is no load, the power supply pulls 2 amps. Why is the power supply pulling 4 amps of current on startup, and what can I do to reduce it?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking, it sounds like you're wondering if you should rely on an external power supply for current limiting your project? If so the answer is probably no. If you're truly require a current limit in order to prevent permanent damage then you should incorporate one with your switch mode power supply chips. that being said most integrated chips like what you're using have thermal overload protection already...

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for your reply. Sorry for not being clear. I think I might have been getting ahead of myself here. So, I readjusted my question to try and be more clear, focusing on the reason why my ICs are pulling 4 amps of current on startup and what I can do about it. Once I understand why (and understanding if there's anything I can do about it), I plan to move on to using a fixed external supply to power my board. I just want to understand what do I have to consider when using an external power supply when switching from a bench supply.

Comment: You have a milifarad of input capacitance directly connected to the power supply. With nothing to limit current, those caps are going to draw as much current as they can get, and once they're full the output caps and load will start doing the same.

Comment: @user1850479 So it's an issue with the caps? I tested this in 3 ways: no-load, load #1, and load #2. No-load and load #2 draw 2 amps on startup, while load #1 draws 4 amps. This occurs as well when I cut the capacitance in half (by removing one capacitor at both inputs and outputs). Adjusting the current-adjust resistors helps by limiting switch current, but that would reduce the max output current. If the input capacitors are needed, what would help limit the current in this case on startup?

Comment: If you want to limit the capacitor inrush current, you have some options, you can passively do it with a resistor or a ntc thermistor. There's a post somewhere on here about it. You also could take an active approach and use something like a fet transistor on the high side to limit current. But that gets more complicated...